# Cannot find pdf file using webView

Tags: cocoa

I am attempting to load a local pdf file using the following code for a Cocoa project (not an iOS project).

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testPDFFile" 
                                                     ofType:@"pdf"
                                                inDirectory:@""];
NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
```

I can see the WebView object is loading, but the document is not shown.  It looks like the Outlet is connected correctly.

I have tried moving the file to various directory locations, and have tried specifying a directory in the inDirectory parameter.

Currently, the file is located in the “Supporting Files” directory.  If I change inDirectory to read…
inDirectory:@”Supporting Files”];  I receive an error that says… “[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter”

How can I get this statement to find and show my file?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testPDFFile" 
                                                     ofType:@"pdf"];
```

As long, as you are accessing resources in your own bundle, you don't have to set a (foreign) bundle directory.

Comment: Thank you, I've been working with that and still don't have it working.  I printed the string using NSLog, and it is looking for a file that is in the directory myApp/Contents/Resources/testPDFFile.pdf  In my file browser, there is no Contents directory under myApp.

Comment: @K17: That's a problem, because a Mac application bundle should have a Contents directory. That directory should in turn contain the Info.plist file, the MacOS directory containing the executable, and a Resources directory.

Comment: The more modern method is [`URLForResource:withExtension:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/URLForResource:withExtension:) (or [`URLForResource:withExtension:subdirectory:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/URLForResource:withExtension:subdirectory:)).

Comment: Thank you both.  The path to info.plist in this project is...

MyCocoaApplication/MyCocoaApplication-info.plist
There is aslo a directory path...
MyCocoaApplication/en.lproj/infoPlist.strings

Also, I tried out the two URLForResource method configurations with the same result.  The compile is successful, the program runs, and when it's time to show the web view, there is a blank web view.  No contents shown.

Comment: I have been researching this further by comparing the Cocoa app to an iOS app that works.  in the iOS app there is a a method... WebView loadRequest, followed by a method ... super viewWillAppear.  Could the problem with the Cocoa app be that my Cocoa app does not have the viewWillAppear?  I've looked for a Cocoa equivalent to viewWillAppear, but can't find one.

Comment: @K17: That's a separate issue. This question is about finding a file within a bundle, and Carsten's answer is the solution to that. You should ask a separate question about whatever problem you're now having with WebView and a view controller or window controller.

Comment: Sometimes a problem presents as one issue, but turns out to be another.  This is one of those situations, and I am adding this final comment with a note about what turned out to be the actual problem. Perhaps it will help someone with a similar issue.  While it looked like the code could not locate the .pdf file, it turned out that the load request method was in the initWithWindow method and it should have been in the WindowDidLoad method.   It now works correctly.  Thank you to those who helped.